# Conditionally replace several columns with default values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` with numerical columns `"A", "B", "C"...` as well as a boolean column `"DEFAULT"`. I also have a list of special columns, for example `special = ["A", "D", "E", "H", ...]`, and a list of corresponding default values: `default = [a, d, e, h, ...]`. What I want to do is: for every row where `DEFAULT` is `True`, replace the values of the special columns by the corresponding default values.

Of course I can manually loop through the dataframe to do so, but that's ugly and probably slow.

I've tried all sorts of intuitive ways like:

```
df[df.DEFAULT][special] = default
```

or

```
df[special] = df[special].where(not df.DEFAULT, default, axis = 1)
```

but none of my attempts worked. I've also read many *similar* questions but none seemed to work for me. Sorry if I missed the right one.

Example of input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,10))
df.columns = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
df["DEFAULT"] = [False,False,True,False,True,False,False,True,True,False]
special = list("ADGI")
default = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Can you post the `pd.DataFrame()` so we  can reproduce it?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but it seems some people like to down vote around here sometimes for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need [`.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) (`ix` would also work):

```
df.loc[df.DEFAULT, special]
Out[40]: 
          A         D         G         I
2  0.629427  0.532373  0.529779  0.274649
4  0.226196  0.467896  0.851469  0.971351
7  0.666459  0.351840  0.414972  0.451190
8  0.238104  0.277630  0.943198  0.293356
```

For assignment:

```
df.loc[df.DEFAULT, special] = default

df
Out[44]: 
          A         B         C         D         E         F         G  \
0  0.513798  0.138073  0.685051  0.173045  0.964050  0.245352  0.360657   
1  0.286920  0.464747  0.301910  0.857810  0.957686  0.684297  0.381671   
2  1.000000  0.454802  0.707585  2.000000  0.777142  0.738670  3.000000   
3  0.894643  0.987747  0.162569  0.430214  0.205933  0.651764  0.361578   
4  1.000000  0.859582  0.014823  2.000000  0.658297  0.875474  3.000000   
5  0.075581  0.848288  0.819145  0.429341  0.718035  0.275785  0.951492   
6  0.984910  0.858093  0.665032  0.138201  0.006561  0.282801  0.050243   
7  1.000000  0.215375  0.594164  2.000000  0.666909  0.598950  3.000000   
8  1.000000  0.931840  0.568436  2.000000  0.911106  0.727052  3.000000   
9  0.140491  0.181527  0.436082  0.617412  0.468370  0.496973  0.426825   

          H         I         J DEFAULT  
0  0.964239  0.422831  0.660515   False  
1  0.650808  0.112612  0.897050   False  
2  0.537366  4.000000  0.243392    True  
3  0.377302  0.341089  0.488061   False  
4  0.074656  4.000000  0.317079    True  
5  0.990471  0.634703  0.141121   False  
6  0.026650  0.731152  0.589984   False  
7  0.570956  4.000000  0.762232    True  
8  0.828288  4.000000  0.359620    True  
9  0.701504  0.050273  0.427838   False
```

Comment: Jeez! I had tried `.ix` and `.loc` but like this: `df.loc[df.DEFAULT][special]`, which doesn't help (of course retrospectively!)  Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You are welcome. The first part (`df.loc[df.DEFAULT]`) is OK but when you select the columns with adding [special] at the end, you are doing chained indexing so the assignment may fail: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing

Answer (score 2):

I think you can first create `dictionary` with lists `special` and `default`, then replace desired values in `df` with columns names and last  [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) them by `dictionary`:

```
maping = dict(zip(special,default))
print maping
{'A': 1, 'I': 4, 'D': 2, 'G': 3}

df.loc[df.DEFAULT, special] = special
df = df.replace(maping)
print df
          A         B         C         D         E         F         G  \
0  0.518990  0.066074  0.472414  0.438256  0.202796  0.423588  0.357758   
1  0.522062  0.035160  0.906231  0.816364  0.552581  0.851809  0.962395   
2  1.000000  0.603323  0.128021  2.000000  0.002065  0.198911  3.000000   
3  0.947822  0.728559  0.329651  0.791761  0.108166  0.392319  0.221218   
4  1.000000  0.506343  0.349898  2.000000  0.024577  0.633987  3.000000   
5  0.316550  0.826805  0.103991  0.633982  0.751032  0.155978  0.426002   
6  0.590585  0.435532  0.798689  0.923456  0.299154  0.388404  0.486272   
7  1.000000  0.263768  0.944626  2.000000  0.720266  0.925395  3.000000   
8  1.000000  0.649534  0.927976  2.000000  0.816151  0.911451  3.000000   
9  0.668218  0.286717  0.019462  0.399222  0.308528  0.942185  0.888265   

          H         I         J DEFAULT  
0  0.163684  0.441374  0.262800   False  
1  0.110522  0.630832  0.997994   False  
2  0.330441  4.000000  0.280859    True  
3  0.683726  0.102446  0.397026   False  
4  0.268709  4.000000  0.955568    True  
5  0.892707  0.103578  0.018096   False  
6  0.588151  0.983854  0.697330   False  
7  0.423054  4.000000  0.367475    True  
8  0.369524  4.000000  0.560451    True  
9  0.860311  0.653000  0.344289   False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Num A' : [1.,2.7, 3.4], 
                     'Def A' : [-1.,-2.7, -3.4], 
                     'DEFAULT' : [True, False, True]})

print df2  

df2.loc[df2['DEFAULT']==True, 'Num A']=df2.loc[df2['DEFAULT']==True, 'Def A']

print df2
```